# ExtJs 3.4 - how to ToolTip a content of a textField component that was pre-loaded

Tags: javascript, extjs3

This is the component where I'm trying to put a Tooltip:

```
this.textFieldStreet = new Ext.form.TextField({
    id          : 'idTextFieldStreet',
    fieldLabel  : 'Street',
    autoCreate  : limitChar(30,30),
    listeners   : {
         render : function(c){
            Ext.QuickTips.register({
                target : c.getEl(),
                html   : '' + Ext.getCmp('idTextFieldStreet').getValue()
                }
            });
         } 
    }
});
```

In another .js I created the function that define every component like you see before and invoke the function as you see forward:

```
var componentFormCustomer = new ComponentFormCustomer();
```

Then I set value like:

```
componentFormCustomer.textFieldStreet.setValue('Some street info')
```

Now, here's the problem, I was looking for some ideas to do that and found nothing, I don't know if this is the right way to accomplish the tooltip. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Define `show` listener for created `tooltip`. In this listener get the value of `textfield` and `update` tooltip. 
With this approach, the tooltip's content will change dynamically and will show the content of tooltip's target.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var textFieldStreet = new Ext.form.TextField({
        renderTo    : Ext.getBody(),
        id          : 'idTextFieldStreet',
        fieldLabel  : 'Street',
        value       : 'Initial value',
        bodyCfg     : {
            tag: 'center',
            cls: 'x-panel-body',
            html: 'Message'
        },
        listeners   : {
            render : function(c) {
                new Ext.ToolTip({
                    target : c.getEl(),
                    listeners: {
                        'show': function (t) {
                            var value = t.target.getValue();
                            t.update(value);
                        }
                    }                   
                });
            }
        } 
    });

    var button = new Ext.Button({
        renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
        text     : 'Change Tooltip',
        handler  : function () {
            textFieldStreet.setValue('New value');
        }
    });
});
```

**Notes:**

Tested with ExtJS 3.4.1.